# Meaning of "Noch" in the following sentences

Tags: adverb

1. Ich mache meine Hausaufgabe *noch*
2. Guten Tag *noch*!

Comment: in future / ongoing .respectively ...

Comment: Noch as in future? wouldn't it be more accurate to use Schon then?

Comment: Check my answer please. _Schon_ is totally off. _"Ich mache noch (schon) meine Hausaufgaben"_ would mean to refer the _ongoing_ thing. Note the words position. _schon noch_ makes the promise weaker (at least for a parents ears).

Comment: I think *noch* when you will do it in the near future. *Schon* when you will do it even faster, right away.

Comment: @Tomas _"when you will do it in the near future"_ or even not :-P ...

Comment: Totally agree hehe. Just to add Ich mache das *schon* is similiar as "I am on it".

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the context, there are different possibilities, since the sentences are a bit imprecise.

> Ich mache meine Hausaufgaben noch.
>
> > Ich mache immer noch meine Hausaufgaben.
> >
> > I am still doing my homework.
> >
> > Ich werde meine Hausaufgaben noch machen.
> >
> > I will do my homework (later at some time).
>
> Guten Tag noch!
>
> > Ich wünsche Dir/Ihnen noch einen guten (restlichen) Tag.
> >
> > Have a nice (remaining) day!
> >
> > (ironisch) Guten Tag noch!
> >
> > (ironically, e. g. if you are angry at someone) Have a nice day!

`schon` can be used to say that you are already doing something ("I am already doing my homework.") **or** similar to `noch` ("I am certainly going to do my homework."). Concerning the latter, the difference is that `schon` implies more certainty. This can best be illustrated by a short example:

> Ich mache das noch (irgendwann).
>
> Keine Sorge, ich mache das schon (bald).

Comment: Good explanation of the possibly _negative connotation_ regarding the 2nd example!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the best translations I am able to give with that narrow context:

> 1. Ich mache meine Hausaufgabe noch
>
>    > I'll *(certainly)* do my homework *(soon)* ***later***.

---

> 2. Guten Tag noch
>
>    > Have a good day ***further on***